# Error in path with django-storages with dropbox

Tags: django, dropbox, dropbox-api, django-storage

This is my settings code

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = "my token"
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = "Apps/Djangoproject"
```

The error i am getting while uploading a image:

```
ValidationError: did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])|id:.)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
how to solve this issue?
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're supplying a path of `"Apps/Djangoproject"`, and the error is indicating that it does not match the expected path format, as shown by the supplied regex pattern. Specifically, in this case it's because non-root Dropbox paths should start with a `"/"`, but yours doesn't.

So, if you have an app with full Dropbox [access](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions) and you want to access that "Djangoproject" folder, your path value should be: `"/Apps/Djangoproject"`. However, if you have an app with app folder access and that "Djangoproject" is your app folder, you should actually just supply the root path value: `""`. (That is, an empty string. Dropbox automatically interprets the root as the app folder for apps with the app folder permission.)