# Django storages backend url pattern error when using dropbox

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api, django-storage

I am trying to use dropbox as a backend storage solution for django using django-storages, i followed the documentation but i am getting this error:

```
'C:/media/post_pics/profile_pic.jpeg' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date = models.DateField(timezone.now())
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics')
```

...and my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Dropbox media file storage

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'myToken'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/media/'
```

Comment: This is effectively the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801365/error-in-path-with-django-storages-with-dropbox . You're supplying a local filesystem URL to the Dropbox API when it's expecting a remote Dropbox path.

Comment: @Greg yep, it was a windows related problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was just a problem with how windows path works, using a linux system solved it